# How to confirm that whether decoder support HLG or HDR format in Android?

Tags: android, exoplayer, android-mediacodec, decoder, hdr

Now, i know that we can get the profiles from the MediaCodecInfo.CodecCapabilities.profiles.
For example, if decoder is hevc, the profiles can be HEVCProfileMain10HDR10 or HEVCProfileMain10HDR10Plus. Is it means that it both support hdr10+ and hdr10 if profile name equals HEVCProfileMain10HDR10Plus?
And then, in [Android developer document][1]

[1]: https://source.android.com/docs/core/display/hdr#vp9-hlg-pq says that if decoder is vp9 and the profile name equals VP9Profile2HDR or VP9Profile2HDR10Plus, it will support HLG. Why not say vp9 support hdr or hdr10+?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a codec supports multiple profiles (`HEVCProfileMain10`, `HEVCProfileMain10HDR10`, `HEVCProfileMain10HDR10Plus`) then we can expect to see all of them listed in the `MediaCodecInfo.CodecCapabilities.profileLevels` array.

Note that when the documentation mentions "HDR video" it means "high dynamic range video" in general. While [HDR10](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HDR10) and [HDR10+](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HDR10%2B) are specific formats of HDR video (along with `HLG10` and Dolby Vision).

So, for example, [VP9](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VP9) Profile 3 (HDR) supports 2 color depths (10 or 12 bit) and 2 transfer functions ([PQ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perceptual_quantizer) or [HLG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid_log%E2%80%93gamma)). But `HDR10` implies 10-bits and `PQ`, while `HLG10` implies 10-bits and `HLG`.

Furthermore, [HEVC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_Efficiency_Video_Coding) Main 10 profile supports multiple transfer functions too. For example, `HEVCProfileMain10` handles `HLG` and `HEVCProfileMain10HDR10` handles `PQ`. And the number 10 in the name stands for 10 bits per sample.

Comment: I still have some doubts. Do you mean the profile "VP9Profile3HDR" support PQ and HLG transfer function and the profile "VP9Profile2HDR" only support PQ function? We can say it implements HLG format if it support HLG and it implements HLG10 format if it support PQ format. Is my opinion right?

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/media/vp9/hdr-encoding), VP9 profiles 2 and 3 support both transfer functions (HLG and PQ). The only difference between the profiles seems to be in the supported chroma subsampling.

Comment: OK，VP9 profiles 2 or 3 both support transfer function HLG and PQ. If VP9 use transfer function PQ and profile is 'VP9ProfileHDR10Plus', is it means decoding HDR10+ video? If use HLG and 'VP9ProfileHDR10Plus', the video format is HLG or HDR10+? And HEVC has profile 'HEVCProfileMain10HDR10' and 'HEVCProfileMain10HDR10plus', while in  [Android developer document][1], it just say HEVC support HDR10 video. I can not understand these. I am very confused about these.
[1]: https://source.android.com/docs/core/display/hdr#technologies

Comment: `VP9ProfileHDR10` is supposed to decode `HDR10` and `HLG10` video while `VP9ProfileHDR10Plus` is supposed to decode `HDR10+` video (there is no HLG format with dynamic metadata yet).